# Open a word doc from my iOS application and edit it in MSWord app and get the edited file back in my application

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a Xamarin ios application from which I need to open/edit a word doc in MSWord app and later get the edited file in my application.

I followed the steps in the below link and unfortunately that didn't work.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office-from-ios-applications

Comment: `unfortunately that didn't work` Add to your question the code and what is not works/exceptions/stacktrace/etc....

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial only works for files hosted in SharePoint or OneDrive.
Unfortunately other cloud services or local files are not supported.

From the link:

> You can enable users who are running Office on an iOS device to open
>   and edit files stored in SharePoint or OneDrive from any application,
>   and then quickly return them to the original application when they're
>   done editing the file.

Comment: If app works on files hosted in SharePoint or OneDrive, Can you share link guide me that work it?

Comment: The link is in the question.

Comment: @Rivera, Is it working for you? Because I tried giving a OneDrive url and it still didn't work for me. The sample url given in their documentation doesn't look like a OneDrive url to me.

Comment: I didn't try as I wanted to edit files not hosted in SharePoint or OneDrive.