# How to open file .doc use "Word" app on Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Use Xamarin Forms and on iOS, how to check and open [Word app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-word/id586447913?mt=8) when Open file by UrL?
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office-from-ios-applications

This is my code, it isn't work:

```
Device.OpenUri(new Uri("ms-word:ofe|u|https://calibre-ebook.com/downloads/demos/demo.docx"));
```

Please help me!
Thanks!

Comment: You need a dependency service for this its not a xamarin forms thing!

Comment: I want write code on iOS. You can supply solution @G.hakim

Comment: I guess [this](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/officewopi/en/latest/overview.html) guide here has necessary information.

Comment: I only want that view file .doc on external app ("Word" app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-word/id586447913?mt=8). 
May be your solution don't fit with me.

Comment: I find a answer is same with your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51494932/open-a-word-doc-from-my-ios-application-and-edit-it-in-msword-app-and-get-the-ed
But you don't want "edit" file, Do you only want "view" file .docx with Word app?when open it to your app.

Comment: Yes, @BillNguyen, Do you have solution for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solution for my project, I try it:

If you only open file .docx on iOS, you could write code at Share Code of iOS:

1. Check device of user has setup app (Word, Excel, PP, etc...)

   ```
   public static bool HasSetupAppDocument(string extension)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
           return false;

       // Device has setup app?
       var result = UIApplication.SharedApplication.CanOpenUrl(NSUrl.FromString($"{extension}"));
       return result;
   }
   ```

(Ex: `extension` is `ms-word:` or `ms-excel:` or `ms-excel:`

**Reference**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/integration/integrate-with-office-from-ios-applications#office-protocols)

**Notes**: Add source to `Info.plist`:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
     <string>ms-word</string>
     <string>ms-excel</string>
     <string>ms-powerpoint</string>
</array>
```

2. At Class Dependencies, open file with `URL`:

   `Device.OpenUri(new Uri($"{convertExtension}{url}"));`

Note: `url` is link file share on [Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/vi-vn/) and Be sure that account [Onedrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/vi-vn/) as same as account login `Word` app (if you had set security).

If file has mode `Read-only`, app `Word` will open file with mode `Read-only`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking here can be done using a simple WebView in iOS:

First, create a custom WebView class that allows you to pick file uri:

```
public class CustomWebView : WebView
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",
            returnType: typeof(string),
            declaringType: typeof(CustomWebView),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Uri
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }
    }

}
```

Then in ios make a renderer for the same and do something like this:

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
  namespace DisplayPDF.iOS
 {
   public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, UIWebView>
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged (e);

        if (Control == null) {
            SetNativeControl (new UIWebView ());
        }
        if (e.OldElement != null) {
            // Cleanup
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null) {
            var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
            string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode (customWebView.Uri)));
            Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false)));
            Control.ScalesPageToFit = true;
          }
       }
   }
}
```

Then use the custom control like this:

```
 <local:CustomWebView Uri="FooPath" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

Where **FooPath** is the path for the doc file.

Comment: Tried this code, but pdf/word files not opening. Showing `NSURLConnection finished with error - code -110`.